# FOC Control vs SVPWM

Tags: pwm, stm32, power-electronics, motor-controller, induction-motor

I wonder how far the similarities go between FOC control and SVPWM modulation and from which point on wards they are different from each other?

edit:

Can anyone point out a very basic primer from where I can learn about SVPWM?

Comment: The concepts are orthogonal. FOC can be implemented with SVPWM.

Comment: Orthogonal... great word!

Comment: A better question would be SVPWM and SPWM

Comment: @JonRB The OP already asked that question, and other related questions: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/420281/spwm-vs-6-step-pwm-vs-svmpwm

Comment: ok good, I guess he is just conflating terms. Looking at that question you just posted

Comment: can anyone point out a very basic ab-anitio introduction to SVPWM.. i am struggling to learn it but most papers i got so far go over and above my head.. and they have so many other things discussed in them that its difficult to make sense of exactly what is SVPWM.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.switchcraft.org/learning/2017/3/15/space-vector-pwm-intro)  is an excellent write-up I found on SVPWM.

From that site:

"Space Vector Pulse Width Modulation (SV-PWM) is a modulation scheme used to apply a given voltage vector to a three-phased electric motor (permanent magnet or induction machine).

The goal is to use a steady state DC-voltage and by the means of six switches (e.g. transistors) emulate a three-phased sinusoidal waveform where the frequency and amplitude is adjustable. ..."

An excellent animated vector diagram is provided on the above page. Unfortunately, the URL is too long for SE EE, and SE EE does not allow use of URL shorteners. A working link can be found in the comments below or by reconstituting https:// bit.ly/svpwmcontrol.

Comment: [Image of SVPWM vectors](https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/584729023e00bebf8abd6ba0/1493085514196-SJ9AGSE5JSO8YKNGOMGG/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kIkSF9sJ4yJljeuN7l2ALQh7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z5QPOohDIaIeljMHgDF5CVlOqpeNLcJ80NK65_fV7S1UQ5O78hEe1S8HpLLkPei_HZkbcBM1C3n9qpKxqMqkIBOZDqXZYzu2fuaodM4POSZ4w/image-asset.gif?format=1500w)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon thank you for the edit. I will be more mindful of this in future posts.